# Add a row in a dataframe taking values from a vector R

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have a df like this

```
df <- data.frame (id = c(123,123,456), w1= c("abc","fgh","kit"), w2 = c("eat","drink","ty"))

   id  w1    w2
1 123 abc   eat
2 123 fgh drink
3 456 kit    ty
```

and a vector

```
vec <- c('value1', 'value2').
```

I would like to add these values to the df when there is a precise correspondance. The final df I'd like to obtain is like this:

```
   id  w1    w2 new_col
1 123 abc   eat  value1
2 123 abc   eat  value2
3 123 fgh drink  no correspondance
4 456 kit    ty  no correspondance
```

I tried this code

```
for (i in 1:length(df$id)) { ## for iterating each row 
  if (df$w2[i] == 'eat') {
    df$new_col[i] <- vec ### how to? Here I need to replace both 'value1' and 'value2' copying the row 
  }
}
```

Can someone suggest me something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `when there is a precise correspondance` care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add a list column to the dataframe and then use `tidyr::unnest` to get them as separate rows.

```
inds <- df$w2 == "eat"
df$new_col[!inds] <- 'no correspondance'
df$new_col[inds] <- list(vec)
tidyr::unnest(df, new_col)

#     id w1    w2    new_col          
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>            
#1   123 abc   eat   value1           
#2   123 abc   eat   value2           
#3   123 fgh   drink no correspondance
#4   456 kit   ty    no correspondance
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tidyr` library:

```
> library(tidyr)
> df[1, 'new_col'] <- toString(vec)
> df %>% separate_rows(new_col)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id w1    w2    new_col
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1   123 abc   eat   value1 
2   123 abc   eat   value2 
3   123 fgh   drink <NA>   
4   456 kit   ty    <NA>   
>
```

**Edit:**

```
> library(tidyr)
> df[1, 'new_col'] <- toString(vec)
> df %>% %>% filter(new_col %in% c('value1', 'value2')) %>% separate_rows(new_col) %>% bind_rows(filter(df, !new_col %in% c('value1', 'value2')))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id w1    w2    new_col
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1   123 abc   eat   value1 
2   123 abc   eat   value2 
3   123 fgh   drink <NA>   
4   456 kit   ty    <NA>   
>
```

Comment: what if I want to apply `separate_rows` only to the first row? I don't want to separate the whole dataframe

Comment: @PersianK It only does it to `new_col` so it should be good

Comment: yes but if for example I have a string instead of NA, how I can keep that string and separate only rows with 'value1' and 'value2' ?

Comment: In edited the question to be clearer. I don't want to split the string 'no correspondance'.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`, we can create a logical condition with `case_when` and return a `list` column, then do the `unnest`ing of the `list` column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(new_col = case_when(w2 == 'eat' ~ list(vec), 
           TRUE ~ list('no correspondance'))) %>% 
   unnest(new_col)
# A tibble: 4 × 4
     id w1    w2    new_col          
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>            
1   123 abc   eat   value1           
2   123 abc   eat   value2           
3   123 fgh   drink no correspondance
4   456 kit   ty    no correspondance
```